# Sum of decimal converted to hours and minutes

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please somebody help me.
I want to sum my overtime hours.

Example :

```
Date    Ot hours    
Feb 2   0.30    
Feb 3   0.30    
Feb 4   0.30    
Feb 5   0.30    
Feb 6   0.30    
Feb 7   0.30    
Feb 8   0.30    
Total   2.10
```

Total should be 3.30 (3 hrs and 30 minutes).

I've tried in SQL :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), floor(sum(floor(OT_HRS)) + sum(OT_HRS - floor(OT_HRS)) * 100.0/60)/1 + ((sum(floor(OT_HRS))/1 + sum(OT_HRS - floor(OT_HRS)) * 100.0/60) % 1) * 60.0/100 ) 
FROM T_SUMMARY_ATTENDANCE 
WHERE OT_HRS is not null
```

Thank You.

Comment: How do you get this data?

Comment: @Sir Tim I've tried in SQL :   select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),
    floor(sum(floor(OT_HRS)) + sum(OT_HRS - floor(OT_HRS)) * 100.0/60)/1 +
       ((sum(floor(OT_HRS))/1 + sum(OT_HRS - floor(OT_HRS)) * 100.0/60) % 1) * 60.0/100
    )
FROM T_SUMMARY_ATTENDANCE
where OT_HRS is not null

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in a table, take the following approach:

- Convert the values to minutes
- Sum the minutes
- Convert back to what you want

So:

```
select sum(ot_hours * 100) as minutes,
       (sum(ot_hours * 100) / 60 +
        sum(ot_hours * 100) % 60) / 100.0
       )
from . . .
```

Having done the arithmetic, I strongly discourage your from storing the data as a number in this format.  If your values are always less than 24 hours, then you can use the `time` data type.  If larger, then I would recommend one of two solutions:

- Store as decimal hours.  So, 90 minutes would be 1.5 hours rather than 1.3.
- Store as strings.  So, 90 minutes would be '01:30'.

These are both standard formats that other people will not find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the expected result.

```
select  cast(cast((SUM(OT_HRS)*100)/60 as int) as varchar(10))+ ':' + cast(cast((SUM(OT_HRS)*100)%60 as int) as varchar(10)) 
from #T_SUMMARY_ATTENDANCE
```